# fgetcsv not removing quotes

Tags: php, csv, double-quotes, fgetcsv

so I have this:

```
$handle = fopen($filepath, 'r');
$row = fgetcsv($handle, null, "\t", '"');
```

whereby $filepath contains a file with the following text:

```
"\A some text with space."
```

but then when I echo the contents of $row, it's not removing the enclosing quotations marks and the variable will still contain the entire string including the quotation marks despite the fact that there are spaces in them...

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What do the spaces have to do with anything?  Your settings indicate you want tabs to separate the values and double quotes to enclose values.  So that string should only return one entry with a value of `\A some text with space.`

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fgetcsv` returns an array, if the file with the content as you said, then the result of `var_dump($row);` should be:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(24) "\A some text with space."
}
```

Then `echo $row[0];` is the result, won't have the quotations.